# Calculate sum of values in Cypress

Tags: cucumber, cypress

I am using BDD/Cucumber with Cypress. I want to calculate the sum of some rows of table.
This is my step definition:

```js
And("I add up all the total on hand",()=>{        
        const sumOnHand = itemListPage.totalOnHandAmsterdam()+itemListPage.totalOnHandDelft()
            cy.log(sumOnHand)
        })
```

And this is my js page:

```js
totalOnHandAmsterdam() {
        cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .dx-grandtotal > span').invoke('text').then(text =>{
            const ttOnHandAmst = text
            return ttOnHandAmst;
        })
    }
```

```js
totalOnHandDelft() {
        cy.get(':nth-child(11) > .dx-grandtotal > span').invoke('text').then(text =>{
            const ttOnHandDelft = text
            return ttOnHandDelft;
        })
    }
```

But this is the output of the calculation:

[image]

Any ideas on how can I sum up this value is appreciated.

Comment: Hi. At first sight, looks like you try to sum 2 different data types. Your `totalOnHandAmsterdam` and `totalOnHandDelft` functions use invoke method for `text`, however, the tracelogs displays `.text()` and `.val()`. Could you check the types of this returned values? ..before returns, log a typeof for `ttOnHandAmst ` and `ttOnHandDelft `.

Comment: also, there might happen that the values are not returned yet, when you try to sum them, so you get `undefined + undefined` which results `NaN`. Try to not use functions in your calculation(it's a bad practice), use already stored outputs, e.g. `const ttOnHandAmst = itemListPage.totalOnHandAmsterdam();  const ttOnHandDelft =  itemListPage.totalOnHandDelft(); const sumOnHand = ttOnHandAmst + ttOnHandDelft;`

Comment: Hi @AlexIzbas. When I used ``` cy.log(typeof itemListPage.totalOnHandAmsterdam())        
        cy.log(typeof itemListPage.totalOnHandDelft())``` it was printed on the console undefined for both, but I added a wait before this function. So I think I need to convert  itemListPage.totalOnHandAmsterdam(); and itemListPage.totalOnHandDelft() to number

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the results of `totalOnHandAmsterdam()` and `totalOnHandDelft()` directly in a summation because

1. they don't return anything (the return inside `.then(text =>` does not return the value from the function).
2. Cypress commands don't return values, they add the values to the command queue

You can do it like this

```js
totalOnHandAmsterdam() {
  return cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .dx-grandtotal > span')
    .invoke('text').then(parseInt)
}

totalOnHandDelft() {
  return cy.get(':nth-child(11) > .dx-grandtotal > span')
    .invoke('text').then(parseInt)
}

And("I add up all the total on hand", () => {   
     
  itemListPage.totalOnHandAmsterdam().then(ams =>  // get value on command queue
    itemListPage.totalOnHandDelft().then(delft =>  // get other value 
      const sumOnHand = ams + delft;
      cy.log(sumOnHand)
    })
  })
})
```

The key to accessing command return values is using `.then()` after the command.

It's annoying but necessary because Cypress ensures that the web page has received data from the server before evaluating the element text.

Since the test runs faster than web page fetches data, it can easily evaluate the `text` before the page is fully populated.

Comment: it worked, it was just missing the letter `e` in parseInt

Comment: My bad, I was in a hurry. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

You could set the function results as aliases.

Since the code is asynchronous, access it within `cy.then()`.

```js
totalOnHandAmsterdam() {
  cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .dx-grandtotal > span')
    .invoke('text')
    .then(parseInt)
    .as('amsterdamTotal')              // alias will set this.amsterdamTotal
}

totalOnHandDelft() {
  return cy.get(':nth-child(11) > .dx-grandtotal > span')
    .invoke('text')
    .then(parseInt)
    .as('defltTotal')                  // alias will set this.delftTotal
}

And("I add up all the total on hand", function() {   // use function() to access "this"
  
  po.totalOnHandAmsterdam()
  po.totalOnHandDelft()

  cy.then(() => {
    const sumOnHand = this.amsterdamTotal + this.defltTotal;
    cy.log(sumOnHand)
  })
})
```

Comment: I got  "parsInt is not defined"

Comment: Ref [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your texts to numbers and then add it. You can simply add `+` in front of the number to convert them into Integers. Also I have added `trim()` in case your strings have any unwanted spaces.

```js
And('I add up all the total on hand', () => {
  const sumOnHand =
    +itemListPage.totalOnHandAmsterdam().trim() + +itemListPage.totalOnHandDelft().trim()
  cy.log(sumOnHand)
})
```